# knockout js radio button click event reset selection

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have bind "checked" and "click" event on a radio button list. But whenever a radio button is clicked, the selection does not stay. I must be doing something really wrong. Really appreciate if you guys can point me to the right direction.

Please see the [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rasikasampath/jhHkD/)

View model:

```
var viewModel = {
    wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
    spamFlavor: ko.observable('cherry'),

    click: function(model){
        console.log(model);
    }
};
```

View:

```
<input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" 
       data-bind="checked: spamFlavor, click:click" />
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the [`click` event documentation:](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_3_allowing_the_default_click_action)

> By default, Knockout will prevent the `click` event from taking any default action.
>   ...
>   However, if you do want to let the default `click` action proceed, just `return true`from your click handler function.

So your radio button is reset because of your `click` handler and to fix it you just need to `return true` at the end:

```
click: function(){
   alert('Hi');
   return true;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sF3ur/).

Comment: Thanks! it means a lot :)

Answer (score 6):

Basically, your click handler won't end up catching that you want to retain the value.

What is happening is that it is going back to default after you select an item.

### Simply try:

`return true;`

As the only code in your `handler`.

#### Fiddle away: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/jhHkD/4/

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, your answer is correct, but i accepted the @nemesv answer, as it was on top. :(

Answer (score 5):

You just remove the click event or use `return true` from click event. Because Knockout prevent the click event from taking any default action. This means that if you use the click binding on an a tag (a link), for example, the browser will only call your handler function and will not navigate to the link’s href

```
var viewModel = {
    wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
    spamFlavor: ko.observable('cherry'),
    /*click: function(){
      alert('Hi');
    }*/
};
```

Or

```
var viewModel = {
    wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
    spamFlavor: ko.observable('cherry'),
    click: function(){
      alert('Hi');
      return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thansk Ling.s, return true from the click event solved the issue. I accepted the @nemesv answer.